# Detecting value change in ng-model without using $watch and form for application having large number of models

Tags: angularjs

My application has a lot of models in the page. I want to detect whether user has changed value of any model on click of save. Using $watch on every model puts too much load, so don't want to use this method. Is there any good approach for this?

Small snippet is like below:

```
 <div>
        <div class="ttere2">
          <input type="radio" name="nc2-radio3" ng-model="nc2PenaltyAfter" value="specificDays" />
           <input class="ggfe1" ng-model="nc2AfterDays" ng-disabled="nc2PenaltyAfter!='specificDays'" type="number" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1" />days</div>
           <div class="admin_wp-line">
              <input type="radio" name="nc2-radio3" ng-model="nc2PenaltyAfter" value="immediately"/> Immediately                                            </div>
        <div class="acfv1">model 1</div>
        </div>
           <div style="margin-top: 20px;"><button ng-click="saveData();">Done</button></div>
............too many inputs go here
 </div>
```

Comment: Is it noticeably slow? $watches are core to angular.

Comment: are they inside a form?

Comment: @pixelbits Yes, it becomes slow user experience wise when we go with custom watchers. Code wise, it is also not a good idea to write 1000+ watchers creating a big code.

Comment: @Jorg No, they are out of form.

Comment: Angular has it's own [form processing functionality](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) you might want to [consider](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/forms.html). It keeps track of input validity etc.

Comment: You could try a module like bindonce - http://ngmodules.org/modules/bindonce

Comment: @Jorg Sure, this can direct to a good way. Thanks!

Comment: @pixelbits It is useful but it would be better if I can find a way that relieves me from custom watching with a detection of change as I need. Thanks!

Comment: 1000+ watchers...If this isn't purely experimental I smell a design flaw.

Comment: @MattWay Number of watchers may change depending on requirements. My concern is to find a methodological solution for this need(detecting change in multiple models) using a single thread.

Comment: @Designeer: I've been there myself (actually much worse ~20K watchers). The best approach depends on your requirements. If you want to be able to tell if anything has truly changed upon saving, you can keep a copy of the original data and compare. If you are OK with a few "false positives" (i.e. your app's sometimes thinkibing there has been a change when it hasn't), the easiest (and most performant) way would be to use `ngForm`'s `$dirty`/`$pristine` properties.

Comment: @MattWay: Not even close. 1000 watchers is a very "regular" number. There are certain kinds of apps that need much more than that (without being experimental or flawed by design).

Comment: @ExpertSystem Truly agree with you but I believe there must be a tricky bypass using angular's highly structured environment to full fill this requirement(probably many apps' need) that can eliminate manual comparing and dependency on form controller. Thanks!

Comment: @Designeer: I don't understand your reasoning. There is the comparing, there is $watching over one or more objects (in various levels of "deepness") and there is the efficient, "callback-like" implementation of the FormController. What more do you need ? Why not the FormController ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.$dirty`! Angular will set this on every element that is bound using ng-model, automatically, when it has been changed. It will also set it on the entire form. You can access it in code like this:

```
if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Angular will provide six useful variables on the form, and every ngModel-bound element in your form: `$dirty` and `$pristine`, `$valid` and `$invalid`, and `$touched` and `$untouched`. You can mix and match these to drive a lot of useful behaviors, and they're available both in your controller (using the expression shown above) and your template (directly).

Comment: Hi Chad, $dirty is set once value of the control is changed, eg. if input value is changed to 2 from initial value of 1, $dirty is set. If user again changes the value from 2 to 1, control reaches to its original state. I need that original value of xyz control is changed at the time of saving data which is not possible using $dirty.